# Overriding persistence methods in Backbone for a custom non-RESTful server

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, backbone.js

I am building a Backbone.js based interface on top of a custom SharePoint-based application which uses SOAP for communication (I use the excellent SPServices jQuery library to talk to the Web Service). From what I know Backbone models use the REST architecture to fetch and update data.

So if I have to customize the CRUD operations, what are the model methods I have to override? Is there a skeletal example I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override the Backbone.sync function.

Here's the documentation: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

And as a reference, here's the source code for the default Backbone.sync function: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1012

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Saw the code and looks like this is the one to use!

Comment: An alternative is to set emulateHTTP to true if your server doesn't support REST. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync-emulateHTTP. Overriding the .sync is probably your best best if you want total control of your AJAX calls and have it go to various end points as well.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 implements REST interface and you can use this interface to perform CRUD operations in SharePoint.

[In this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) you can find more information.

The backbone collection only needs to specify the correct URL and a simple parse function.

```
window.Products = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: Product,
    url: "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products",
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.d.results;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Pau. This is news to me. I am currently using SP2007 though our IT team is moving the infrastructure to SP 2010. This is great news that SP 2010 supports the REST API!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint 2010, you may consider using the SharePoint REST interface (ListData.svc), which is quite easy to connect to Backbone. You will need to provide custom parse() and sync() methods.

I wrote a Backbone plugin for SharePoint, which you may find useful. It provides a full CRUD for SharePoint items based on this REST interface. It shows how to extend Backbone's Model and Collection and use a custom sync() and parse() to easily work with SharePoint items and list.

Using this plugin, you can code your access to SharePoint like this:

```
var Contact = Backbone.SP.Item.extend({
    site: '/teamsite',
    list: 'Contacts'
});

var contact = new Contact({LastName: "Delaney"});

var contact.save();
```

You can find the plugin on GitHub: https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint

Comment: Istak, I read your answer only after the previous post by Pau. Wow! This solves my problem to the best extent. Once I start using SP 2010, this would be of great help. Thanks for putting it up on Github.